# QueryDSL can not find all by an array of identifiers as parameter

Tags: querydsl, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using spring-data-mongodb:1.2.0.RELEASE and QueryDSL:2.9.0.

I have a class as follow:

```
@Document(collection = "A")
public class A {
public BigInteger id;
}
```

And a repository as follow:

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends MongoRepository<A, BigInteger>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<A>
```

When I'm querying me repository as follow:
    QA.a.id.eq(a.id)

All is fine, I can see in the mongo db log the next query:

```
query db.A query: { _id: ObjectId('51b8a1dfea34feab29624713') }
```

But when I'm quering with an array of identifiers

```
QA.a.id.in(a.id,a.id)
```

I get nothing.
I can see that the query is:

```
    command db.$cmd command: { count: "A", query: { _id: { $in: [    "25291516816863698974474381015",      "25291516816863698974474381015" ] } } }
```

Which is not using the ObjectId wraping.
So, is it a bug?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a Querydsl bug, since Querydsl also doesn't do any wrapping of the argument for _id eq something.

Comment: Yes i have got the same problem probably bug in querydsl